# why css code did not work

Tags: html, css

```
<STYLE>
    #object1{
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        border-radius:100%;
        background:skyblue;
        animation-name animation1;
        animation-duration 2s;
    } @keyframes animation1 {
        0% { transform: translatex(0px); }
        100% { transform: translatex(300px); }
    }
</STYLE>
<div id="object1"></div>
```

Comment: Please tidy up the question and also what "does not work"?

Comment: Please add some more information, what does not work? What should happen? etc.. maybe a fiddle or snippet?

Comment: I put your code in a codepen and it seems to work, what are you looking for? http://codepen.io/k185/pen/vxoRGm

Comment: Correct how you have specify your animation to this animation: animation1 2s .....................

Comment: i'm try to see a skyblue circle move across the browser,i have used IE, chrome and mozzila to render it , but i can't see animation

Answer (score 0):

The problem should be with syntax in your file, you missed ":" before animation-name. 
If it's not your problem, add html-part!